# websockets wont publish with tomcat 7 using xml mapping

Tags: java, angularjs, xml, sockets, tomcat

I am working on a Tomcat Web-Socket server. I have successfully made the server and connected it with an angularJS Client.

Now I am trying to import the classes into my original project that uses tomcat 7.0.56 and a web.xml for servlet mapping .

the server start fine but gives the following error when instantiating socket

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FirstWebSocketCMS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sss.discovery.FirstWebSocketCMS</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstWebSocketCMS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FirstWebSocketCMS</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Server Side :

```
12:20:51,167 INFO  [FirstWebSocketCMS] Constructor: FirstWebSocketCMS 
Nov 02, 2015 12:20:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet FirstWebSocketCMS as unavailable
Nov 02, 2015 12:20:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet FirstWebSocketCMS
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sss.discovery.FirstWebSocketCMS cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
```

Client Side :

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/sr/FirstWebSocketCMS' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

All works fine if i remove the web.xml content and add the following annotation to the class:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/FirstWebSocketCMS")
public class FirstWebSocketCMS {
}
```

Comment: Are you deploying any kind of servlet-api.jar with your application? If so - remove it.

Comment: @Gimby if i remove the servlet-api.jar from tomcat lib

Nov 02, 2015 4:50:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

Comment: Yes but then you are translating "don't deploy with the application" to "remove from tomcat lib folder" all on your own, I didn't say that nor anything close to it.

Comment: @Gimby can you please explain what you mean by "don't deploy with the application" then ?